# Facebook Login via Manual Flow

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, oauth

I'm trying to use the OAuth flow to login a user via the manual flow.
I have a button with the href pointing to:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v14.0/dialog/oauth?
  client_id={462632115264696}
  &redirect_uri={"localhost:8080"}
  &state={"{st=state123abc,ds=123456789}"}
```

But I only get an error page from facebook saying:

> Sorry, something went wrong

I have tried different parameters without sucess.

Answer (score 2):

Figure it out it has to be without the brackets {}

```
https://www.facebook.com/v14.0/dialog/oauth?
  client_id=462632115264696
  &redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080
  &state="{st=state123abc,ds=123456789}"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).